# Mouthboard Type App for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, plugins, cordova

I am developing an app for the iPhone with similar functionality to the Keith Lemon Mouthboard app so i'm looking for a video plugin that allows you to select videos from a playlist. Has anyone got any recommendations for xcode or phonegap?

Comment: Why not write it yourself? It would just be a `UITableView` and the `MPMoviePlayer` and friends.

Comment: I did have a little play with MPMoviePlayer but found it buffered slightly in between each video so I was wondering if there are any other options out there.

Comment: Are the videos local or remote? If they are remote (or being streamed), of course there will be buffering. And, to answer directly, no. Apple wants you to use their classes for everything their classes provide, and I doubt they will allow an app that has a completely different video player than the rest of iOS. It would break their guidelines.

Comment: The videos are local, obviously I would expect buffering if they were being streamed but even being local there is a slight bit of buffering when moving from one video to the next.

Comment: I've just found AVQueuePlayer within the Apple developer documents so I guess there are other options out there. Does anyone have any experience (good or bad) with AVQueuePlayer?

Comment: Edit your question to add your latest comment. That will push it where it might get some attention. I, for one, have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

We made the app in question, depending on what you are planning to release then we can assist but would need to know exactly what it is you are making and what you intend it to be as obviously we have plans for further uses of the codebase too.
you can email me joe "at" widebeamdigital {dot} com.
Sorry this isn't an open answer to help all, a general answer would be:
The selection queue of videos is a simple array that is worked through, the video is loaded in but under a static jpeg still frame from an average mouth permission, the jpeg is removed as the video is detected as starting to play, then each video has a float value data item associated with it that lets the jpeg know what time to return to fade up over the last few frames of the video. This is how jumps of black are prevented.